# Ignore some fields that are not found in the object

Tags: c#, mongodb

While using MongoDB and C#, is there a way to ignore fields not found in the object?

I am getting below exception for one of field 
Element 'Contact' does not match any field or property of class.

I dont want to use this property for my business logic.

How can we ignore this property?